# Integrating Zxing Barcode scanner to my android app

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to integrate barcode scanner in my android app.

These are the things i have done:

1) i added core-3.2.1 module to my project. 
2) added an activity

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<activity
android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>
```

I'm getting that Cannot resolve symbol 'CaptureActivity'.
What should i do more?

I have checked other stackoverflow posts but i'm unable to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add zxing library to your app via gradle dependency

just add this to your `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
```

Now in your onCreate method of your activity , do the following

```
 IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
 scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan a Barcode");
 scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true); 
 scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
 scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
 scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

You can find a sample project [here](https://github.com/sshuvro58/BarCodeScanner)

Comment: Now it's working. Thanks. What does setBeepEnabled do. And in my code setBarcodeImageEnabled is shoing in red. What do these both methods do?

Comment: "setBeepEnabled" means everytime you scan a barcode  your phone will make a "beep" sound and  "setBarcodeImageEnabled" means it will capture the image .  If you don't need that you can comment out that . If this answer works for you , please accept this as an answer .

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use give dependencies in app.gradle file than use scanner view for scan barcode

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3'
} 

ZXingScannerView mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        Handler handlerThread = new Handler();
        handlerThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResult(Result result) {

                        Log.e(TAG, result.getText());


                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added module reference into your project.
1) New -> Import new Module -> Select your zxing library. Let the gradle build.

Then, Go to File -> Project Structure -> Select app under modules -> Go to Dependency tab -> add zxing module by clicking on green add button.

Rebuild your project